# Inserting new data into a record in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-query

I'm trying to insert data collected from a html form into an existing document. These will all be new fields and these are a python `dict`. However when I perform the insert or update it seems to override the original data.

I initially store the data as:

```
self.settings['db'].userInfo.insert(userData)
```

Then performed the update/insert as:

```
self.settings['db'].userInfo.update({'_id':DBid},locData)
```

My record now just holds data for the latter `update`.

How can I keep the original data in the document and just add in new data later on?

**EDIT**

I was able to add new values into the document by:

```
self.settings['db'].userInfo.update({'_id':DBid},{"$set":userData})
```

I used the same `dict` as before now and used the `$set` operator. This appended the document with the new fields and thier values.

Comment: Try to be more clear next time.

Answer (score 3):

You should be doing another insert, not an update.

An update changes the original value... That's what it's designed to do, so another insert will add a new record to the collection.

To keep all the old fields of the document, and add some more use the **Operator** `$set`.

[image: $set frm Mongo]
[image: Example using $set]

Comment: I meant I wanted it added it to the existing document not creating a new record. I have edited my question to how I added the new data into the document.

Comment: you could add an array of something, but it could snowball to exceed the size limit.  It seems to me that you are asking about schema design, but not giving any real information about this schema

Comment: you want to save ONE old value, or ALL the old values?

Comment: I want to keep all the old values

Comment: you can push them onto an array... but in the long run it MAY ( or may not ) try to exceed the max size limit )

Comment: Without seeing your schema, because you do not give it, I would probably add a new record not update the existing one, even if a good portion of the existing record is the same... but it depends

Comment: I wanted to add it to the existing record as I'm collecting user data from a html form. The original insert is their personal details and depending on their preferences they fill in another form which I just want the form data added onto this existing record. That's why I've used `update`.